# Apply class to every 4,5,6 element in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi I want to apply a class to every 4,5,6 element and keep repeating that there after.

HTML

```
<div class="parent-div">
        <div [ngClass]="{'child-div3' : i > 4 }" class="child-div1">
          <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child-div2">
          <img class="object-fit_contain" [src]="deal.image">
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.child-div1 {
    margin: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.child-div3 {
    margin: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: rgb(236, 147, 29);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

How can i do this?

EDIT:

Here is Stackblitz code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-itn1pc

Thanks.

Comment: where does i variable come from? should put full code

Comment: Yes, place the TS file

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: added stackblitz code. However the code below provided by @Dewanshu does work, but i also need it to pick only every 4,5,6 element and then repeat so then i would need it to pick 10,11,12 and then 15,16,17 and so on. Assuming the first number is 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a check function in your `.ts` file

```
check(i: number) {
        return Math.floor(i / 3) % 2;
}
```

every-time pass your variable `i` in the `check()` function like this

```
<div class="parent-div">
<div[ngClass]="check(i)?'child-div3':'child-div1'">
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-div2">
      <img class="object-fit_contain" [src]="deal.image">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dewanshu the above code works but i'd also need it to also need it to pick only every 4,5,6 element and then repeat so then i would need it to pick 10,11,12 and then 15,16,17 and so on. Assuming the first number is 1 and not 0. How would i do that?

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to achieve. Please elaborate

Comment: ok i have an *ngFor that loops through some data. For the first 3 div's i want to apply classA and for the next 3 i want to apply classB and then the next 3 i want to go back to classA, i want to continue that rotation until the end of the loop. Thank you hope that is clear.

Comment: ok i understand now. I am going to edit my answer please check.

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for thank you so much @Dewanshu